# Eclipse SWT Shell to JInternalFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I'm starting to work with Eclipse SWT and I have the following questions.

The next class opens a window with the word document referenced in the "archivo" variable.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWTError;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleFrame;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class ArchivoMSOffice {

    protected static OleClientSite clientSite;
    protected static OleFrame frame;

    public ArchivoMSOffice() {

    }

    public void run(archivo) {      
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText(archivo);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        try {
            frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);
            //esto abre un documento existente
            clientSite = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NULL, new File(archivo));
        } catch (SWTError e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open activeX control");
            display.dispose();
            return;
        }
        shell.setSize(800, 600);
        shell.open();//this open de Window

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

How can I do to make that window be a JInternalFrame?

Thanks for the help.
Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two toolkits. Your code is using SWT, but `JInternalFrame` is coming from Swing toolkit. SWT and Swing are two completely different ways how to code UI in Java.

[There are some possibilities about how to integrate SWT and Swing](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html), but I am afraid that you cannot just "convert" SWT Window into JInternalFrame. If for nothing else, Window represents real window on screen while JInternalFrame is so-called lightweight object in Swing, it doesn't represent window at OS level.